# Parenthesis Check within a Linked stack for infix to postfix

Tags: java, stack

I have four classes.

1. One contains my linkedstack setup
2. One is infixtopostfix for prioritization and conversion
3. Parenthesis for matching
4. Postfix for evaluation

I have setup almost everything here but it is still returning false anyway I put it. 
On another note my equals on `!stackMatch.pop().equals(c)` is not working due to it being a object type with '!' being a problem.

My programs are simple and straight forward:

**LinkedStack.java**

```
public class LinkedStack implements StackInterface {
    private Node top;

    public LinkedStack() {

        top = null;

    }  // end default constructor

    public boolean isEmpty() {

        return top ==  null;

    }  // end isEmpty


    public void push(Object newItem) {

        Node n = new Node();
        n.setData(newItem);
        n.setNext(top);
        top = n;

    }  // end push

    public Object pop() throws Exception {

        if (!isEmpty()) {
            Node temp = top;
            top = top.getNext();
            return temp.getData();
        } else {
            throw new Exception("StackException on pop: stack empty");
        }  // end if

    }  // end pop

    public Object peek() throws Exception {

        if (!isEmpty()) {
            return top.getData();
        } else {
            throw new Exception("StackException on peek: stack empty");
        }  // end if

    }  // end peek

}  // end LinkedStack
```

**InfixToPostfix.java**

```
import java.util.*;

public class InfixToPostfix {

    Parenthesis p = new Parenthesis();
    LinkedStack stack = new LinkedStack();
    String token = "";  // each token of the string
    String output = ""; // the string holding the postfix expression
    Character topOfStackObject = null;  // the top object of the stack, converted to a Character Object
    char charValueOfTopOfStack = ' '; // the primitive value of the Character object

    /**
     * Convert an infix expression to postfix. If the expression is invalid, throws an exception.
     * @param s the infix expression
     * @return the postfix expression as a string
     * hint:  StringTokenizer is very useful to this iteratively
     */
    //public String convertToPostfix(String s) throws Exception {


     //}



    private boolean isOperand (char c){
        return ((c>= '0' && c <= '9') || (c >= 'a' && c<= 'z'));
    }
    public void precedence(char curOp, int val) throws Exception {
        while (!stack.isEmpty()) {

            char topOp = (Character) stack.pop();
            //     charValueOfTopOfStack = topOfStackObject.charValue();


            if (topOp == '(') {
                stack.push(topOp);
                break;
            }// it's an operator
            else {// precedence of new op
                int prec2;

                if (topOp == '+' || topOp == '-') {
                    prec2 = 1;
                } else {
                    prec2 = 2;
                }

                if (prec2 < val) // if prec of new op less
                { //    than prec of old
                    stack.push(topOp); // save newly-popped op
                    break;
                } else // prec of new not less
                {
                    output = output + topOp; // than prec of old
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**Parenthesis.java**

```
import java.util.*;
public class Parenthesis{

    private LinkedStack stack = new LinkedStack();
    private Object openBrace;
    private String outputString;


    /**
     * Determine if the expression has matching parenthesis using a stack
     *
     * @param expr the expression to be evaluated
     * @return returns true if the expression has matching parenthesis
     */
    public boolean match(String expr) {

    LinkedStack stackMatch = new LinkedStack();


    for(int i=0; i < expr.length(); i++) { 

       char c = expr.charAt(i);
        if(c == '(')
            stackMatch.push(c); 


        else if(c == ')'){
             if (stackMatch.isEmpty() || !stackMatch.pop().equals(c))
             return false;
        }
    }
    return stackMatch.isEmpty();
}
}
```

Just wanted to give you all of it so you could help me. I have tests written already just struggling with the parenthesis problem of pushing it on the stack but unable to compare it to the closing parenthesis so it can check if there is enough while checking to be sure it is not empty.

Answer (score 0):

The problem probably is, that you are trying to test if matching `(` is currently on top of the stack when `)` comes, but in `c` is acctual character, `)`, so you test if `)` is on top of stack, not `(` as you should.